# Unable to filter out internal traffic using cookies in Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics

This is my code related to Google Analytics in my header:

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-ID"> </script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-ID');
</script>
```

This is the code inside my JavaScript file included at the bottom:

```
// Send Google Analytics data if the cookie does not exist
if (document.cookie.indexOf("internalTest=") === -1) {
    window.ga = window.ga || function () {
        (ga.q = ga.q || []).push(arguments)
    };
    ga.l = +new Date;
    ga('create', 'UA-ID', 'auto');
    ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

The cookie `homeTest` exists on my laptop but it still shows in real time data in Analytics.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a mixture of `gtag.js` and `analytics.js`.

The function `gtag('config', 'UA-ID');` is already sending a pageview by default. Instead of this use something like this`gtag('config', 'GA_TRACKING_ID', { 'send_page_view': false });` to prevent the pageview from being sent automatically.

For more information about working with `gtag.js`, refer to [their documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/).

If your setup heavily depends on `analytcs.js` (still perfectly supported by Google), just switch your analytics snippet to something like this

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

When doing a completely new setup, Google recommends using `gtag.js`.

The easiest solution in your case would be putting the `gtag('config', 'UA-ID');` in your if statement.

Comment: Thanks Silver. Which one should I be using on the website? I thought they were both same.

Comment: For a new site use `gtag.js`, if you already use `analytics.js` continue using that. More details: https://reflectivedata.com/gtag-js-migrate/

Comment: @VineetSharma if my answer was sufficient, please mark it as an answer. If not let me know what's missing.

Comment: I was testing to see if it works. I have upvoted it now. :D